# Is there a way to export the PowerPoint?

Tags: javascript, canvas, gojs

I wanna export GoJs diagrams to Microsoft Office PowerPoint. so examined it, but I couldn't get a good result.

Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best way.

Gojs can't export to PowerPoint, but I can get diagram objects.

Using that object, write an intermediate json file.

We grasp the state of diagram from that json and create a PowerPoint using apache poi.

apache poi https://poi.apache.org/

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, jpeg image type is supported.

```
myDiagram.makeImage({
      scale: 1,
      background: "AntiqueWhite",
      type: "image/jpeg"
    });
```

The following image is a jpeg created with an AntiqueWhite background specified.

[image]

Please refer to [documentation](http://gojs.net/latest/intro/makingImages.html) in this page for more information.